# ASP.NET MVC Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, object-reference

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647266/asp-net-mvc-html-textbox-throws-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-a) here on SO but I believe mine differs a little a bit.

OK, so I have a simple view here:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RootFinder.Models.QuadCalc>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Polynomial Root Finder - Quadratic
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Quadratic</h2>

    <%= Html.BeginForm("Quadratic", "Calculate") %>
    <% { %>
    <div>
        a: <%= Html.TextBox("quadAValue", Model.quadraticAValue) %>
        <br />
        b: <%= Html.TextBox("quadBValue", Model.quadraticBValue) %>
        <br />
        c: <%= Html.TextBox("quadCValue", Model.quadraticCValue) %>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="quadraticSubmitButton" value="Calculate!" />
        <br />
        <p><%= Model.x1 %></p>
        <p><%= Model.x2 %></p>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

And my controller here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RootFinder.Models;

namespace RootFinder.Controllers
{
    public class CalculateController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Calculate/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ViewResult Quadratic()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ViewResult Quadratic(QuadCalc newQuadCalc)
        {
            return View(newQuadCalc);
        }

        public ActionResult Cubic()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Quartic()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, upon loading my `Get` version of the `Quadratic` view, I get the following message from VS2010:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Now, I kind of understand the message in it of itself, but isn't it a bad thing to create a new object of a class within the View itself?  Which is why I was trying to handle this in the Controller for the `Post` only.....

Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you do in your Post action, but in the Get you pass a new fresh initialized QuadCalc model to the view

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ViewResult Quadratic() {
    return View( new QuadCalc() );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks again! :)  Now, is the syntax you provided produce the same results as the syntax I provided in my Post, just a matter of preference?  Or do they mean different things?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by sintax :) Do you mean the format? I have just copied your code and formatted as I like. If this was'nt your meaning please let me understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that's what I mean.  I was just referring to the fact that you placed parentheses `()` within the `return view()`.  Mine returned the object.  But, it's slightly different than the post, like you said, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. It's slightly different because in the action with the POST verb you already have a model class coming back from the view. You just fill it up with result and send it back. In the GET action, you need a new object to be created, that's the way you have parenthesis. If you create the object outside the `return View()` instruction then you dont need it as well.