# How to customize the "The value 'foo' is not valid for Number." error message?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetaData))]
public partial class Person {
    public class PersonMetaData {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="The number is required")]
        public object Number {get;set;}
    }
}
```

This error message is shown when the number field is empty and when there's an invalid input it gives "The value 'foo' is not valid for Number.". How can I customize the latter error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Custom validation message for value types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646270/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-message-for-value-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC - Custom validation message for value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646270/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-message-for-value-types/1374653#1374653)