# With ASP.NET MVC, how to display errors when outside controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to easily display errors in my View from anywhere in my code using :

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Before MVC, I used :

```
ValidationError.Display("My error message");
```

And my `ValidationError` class looks like this:

```
public class ValidationError : IValidator
{
    private ValidationError(string message)
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
        IsValid = false;
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public void Validate()
    {
        // no action required
    }

    public static void Display(string message)
    {
        // here is the only part I would like to change ideally
        var currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;                
        currentPage.Validators.Add(new ValidationError(message));
    }

}
```

Now with MVC, to add errors, I can't use `currentPage.Validators`.
I need to use `ModelState` but **my problem is that I can't access `ModelState` when I'm not in the Controller**. I tried accessing the controller or the `ModelState` via `HttpContext` but I've not found a way to do it. Any idea ?

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "My error message");
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify your models and views ?

Comment: yes for the Views but I would prefer not to modify the Models, I think the solution would become too "heavy/complex"

Comment: So can you modify ValidationError class? BTW where IValidator come from?

Comment: yes I can, my goal is to modify only the ValidationError class ideally, IValidator comes from using System.Web.UI;

Comment: I think your question need some updates :) How do you actually use ValidationError into your ASP.Net MVC ? Show us one action that use it. Is it necessary to always ValidationError or we can get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. You can access it through `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState`. Then use

```
@if (!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>There are some errors</div>
}
```

OR

```
ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("NameOfInput")
```

get a list of inputs:

```
var errors = ViewData.ModelState.Where(n => n.Value.Errors.Count > 0).ToList();
```

#### 2. You can pass your model state around like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void errorMessage(ModelStateDictionary ModelState) {
        if (something) ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Message");
    }
}
```

Use in controller:

```
MyClass.errorMessage(ModelState);
```

Use in view:

```
MyClass.errorMessage(ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid);
```

#### 3. `ModelState` via `ActionFilter`

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
          if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
          {
                //Do Something 
          }
     }
}
```

You can get more help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720823/how-do-i-access-other-attribute-values-from-inside-a-custom-validationattribute)  and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx/) links.

Comment: thanks ... I tried it but ViewData is only accessible when in Controller or View, it's not accessible when outside (example : a custom class responsible for importing some data). I think a workaround would be to pass the ModelState to that class in the Constructor but I was hoping to keep it more simple.

Comment: @JohnMarston I update my answer. can you please try?

Comment: thanks for the updated answer ... indeed this would work but my goal is to avoid passing the ModelState and getting it via HttpContext or something like that but it might not be possible ... it might sound picky but imagine you have 300 calls to .errorMessage() to change :P I marked your answer as helpful since it can be used as a workaround