# How manage a View (Validation and Binding etc) for Different models in a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Consider a user can create a Sale advertising (Post model). but every advertising have different properties depend on its Group. Properties are not certain and can be added by admin with different constraints(Required. MinLength etc.)

I define a class like this:

```
public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public InputType Type { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    [Required()]

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Values { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupProperty> GroupProperties { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostProperty> PostProperties { get; set; }

}
```

For example admin can add a model's car property to cars group. after that users must fill a model car field for advertisings in car group.

Create view for advertising is like this:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Property>

<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>New Advertising</h1>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
                    }
                    <button type="submit">hvah</button>
                }

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Ah everything goes harder! I have a Editor template for Property class like this:

```html
@model Property


@helper Helper(Property model)
{
    switch (model.Type)
    {
        case WebSite.Models.DomainModels.InputType.NonNegative:
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="@(model.Name)">@(model.Title)</label>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid  text-danger" data-valmsg-for="@(model.Name)" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    <input class="form-control  text-box single-line valid" data-val="true"
 name="@(model.Name)" type="number" value="0"/>
                </div>
                return;
            }

        case WebSite.Models.DomainModels.InputType.RequiredShortString:
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="@(model.Name)">@(model.Title)</label>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="@(model.Name)" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true"

                           id="@(model.Name)" name="@(model.Name)" type="text" value="BB"/>
                </div>

                return;
            }
    }
}

@Helper(Model)
```

After all i have Client validation for properties. with hard code i can validate them in server side too. but new problem is Binding! if server side validation goes wrong i need to pass a model to view again. so i am think im doing this with a wrong way. can some one help me? maybe about how solve my problem or a better way to implement this? a simple way to use MVC validation On a complex model like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a class and validate `ModelState`. you can do it like-

Example:

You can pass your model state around like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void errorMessage(ModelStateDictionary ModelState) {
        if (something) ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Message");
    }
}
```

Use in controller:

```
MyClass.errorMessage(ModelState);
```

If you need more information about modaestate validation outside then you can fiend more help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826280/with-asp-net-mvc-how-to-display-errors-when-outside-controller/43827128#43827128) link.