# How can I validate a property based on a value in a parent Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, validationattribute

I've got a website where people can apply for services.  They select a product and options they'd like, along with information about themselves.

The model is divided into parts:

```cs
public class ApplicationInformationModel
{
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    public ClientModel Client { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClientModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [AgeValidation]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The age is dependent on the type of the product, but I don't have access to the `ProductType` variable from the `ClientModel`.

```cs
    public class AgeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string GetErrorMessage() => $"The age does not fall within the acceptable range.";

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            int productType = // How do I get the productType?
            var dob = (DateTime)value;
            int age = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dob.DayOfYear) age--;

            if (productType == 0 && age < 18)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            else if (productType == 1 && age < 21)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

How do I get access to the `ProductType`?

Comment: Check if this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720823/how-do-i-access-other-attribute-values-from-inside-a-custom-validationattribute#answer-3721211

Answer (score 0):

> implement **IValidatableObject** in ApplicationInformationModel

```
public class ApplicationInformationModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    public ClientModel Client { get; set; }
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //int productType = productType;

        DateTime dob = Client.DateOfBirth;
        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dob.DayOfYear) age--;

        if (productType == 0 && age < 18)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        else if (productType == 1 && age < 21)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

> Change to **ClientModel has a ApplicationInformationModel**.

```
public class ApplicationInformationModel
{
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClientModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AgeValidation]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public ApplicationInformationModel applicationInformationModel { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then create a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute`, and override the `IsValid` method.

```
public class AgeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string GetErrorMessage() => $"The age does not fall within the acceptable range.";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        ClientModel client = (ClientModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        int productType = client.applicationInformationModel.productType;

        DateTime dob = client.DateOfBirth;
        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dob.DayOfYear) age--;

        if (productType == 0 && age < 18)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        else if (productType == 1 && age < 21)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Links :  [To apply a custom validation attribute to a data field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/cc668224(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-apply-a-custom-validation-attribute-to-a-data-field)

Comment: But I need the validation message to be displayed near the Date of Birth field.  I realize now that may sound a little strange in this simple example I created to try and simplify my question.  The product will actually be selected on a previous page and can no longer be edited when the Date of Birth is entered.

Comment: I don't think this will work anyway as you wouldn't be able to cast `value` to an `int` and a `DateTime`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice the `var dob = (DateTime)value; ` before.    Already update the answer for u.

Comment: Hi, @Joel MacKenzie, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.